# Get TexCoords of vertices in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, textures, shader, lwjgl

Is there anyway to get the TexCoords of the vertices inside the fragment shader or to give them to the fragment shader from the vertex shader, without giving them from the normal code to the vertex shader?

Answer (score 1):

If you have read *any* tutorial, you'd know this is pretty much required for any reasonable texturing.

VS:

```
attribute vec2 in_texCoord;
out vec2 fs_texCoord;

main () {
    fs_texCoord = in_texCoord;
}
```

FS:

```
in vec2 fs_texCoord;
out vec4 out_color;

main () {
    out_color = vec4(fs_texCoord, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

All of the rules regarding interpolation/filtering still apply.

Comment: That way i have to give them to the vertex shader. Is there anyway to read them from the OpenGL state?

Comment: @Geosearchef as a constant? uniform. Why can't you use the vertex shader?

Comment: @Geosearchef: How do you want to read something from the OpenGL state, that's not part of the OpenGL state? It's **your** job to specify the texture coordinates. Either by explicitly submitting them as a vertex attribute, or by procedurally generating them in the shader.